# Bounding integral expression with BV norm of integrand

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Consider the following integral expression:
$$\mathcal I :=\iint_{\epsilon \leq|x-y| \leq 1/2} f(x) f(y) \frac{\langle g(x)-g(y), x-y\rangle}{|x-y|^{n+2}}  d x d y $$
for $\epsilon>0$, $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R)$ and $f$ *compactly supported*.

If $g \in BV(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R^n)$, is it true that
$$\mathcal I \lesssim TV(g)$$
or something of this nature (possibly adding the $\epsilon$ somewhere)?

Related questions are [Bounding integral expression with Sobolev norm of integrand](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425495/bounding-integral-expression-with-sobolev-norm-of-integrand) and [Bounding integral expression with total variation of integrand](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425400/bounding-integral-expression-with-total-variation-of-integrand?rq=1)

---

**Info on BV functions:**
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. We say that $u \in L^{1}(\Omega; \mathbb R)$ is a function of bounded variation in $\Omega$ if the distributional derivative of $u$ is representable by a finite Radon measure in $\Omega$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} u \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_{i}} d x=-\int_{\Omega} \phi d D_{i} u \quad \forall \phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega), \quad i=1, \ldots, N
\end{align*}
for some $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-valued measure $D u=\left(D_{1} u \ldots . D_{n} u\right)$ in $\Omega$.

For functions $u \in B V(\Omega; \mathbb R^m)$, $D u$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of measures $D_{i} u^{\alpha}$ in $\Omega$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} u^{\alpha} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_{i}} d x=-\int_{\Omega} \phi d D_{i} u^{\alpha} \quad \forall \phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega), i=1 \ldots, n, \alpha=1 \ldots  m
\end{align*}

Note that Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is contained in $B V(\Omega)$: indeed, for any $u \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ the distributional derivative is given by $\nabla u \mathcal{L}^{n}$.

For $u \in L_{\text {loc }}^{1}(\Omega; \mathbb R^m)$. The total variation $TV(u, \Omega)$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
TV(u, \Omega):=\sup \left\{\sum_{\alpha=1}^{m} \int_{\Omega} u^{\alpha} \operatorname{div} \varphi^{\alpha} d x: \varphi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega; \mathbb R^{m n}), \|\varphi\|_{\infty} \leq 1\right\}
\end{align*}
Note that $TV(u, \Omega)=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u| d x$ if $u$ is continuously differentiable in $\Omega$.

We remark that $u \in L^{1}((\Omega); \mathbb R^{m})$ belongs to $BV(\Omega; \mathbb R^m)$ if and only if $TV(u, \Omega)<\infty$.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in one post is not encouraged on MathOverflow, and doing so may not be most beneficial for askers. Can you take this into consideration?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Split in two. Here's the second half

Comment: How do you define $TV(g)$ in this case?

Comment: @IosifPinelis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_n_%3E_1_real_variables

Comment: That definition is for real-valued functions, whereas your $g$ is vector-valued. Also, it is unclear from that Wikipedia article how they define the $L^\infty$ norm for vector functions. On a related note, do you want a specific dependence on $n$ and/or $\epsilon$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I've added the definition of BV function and TV to the question. For the dependence on $\epsilon$: ideally I would like it to be uniform (the 1d computation you did suggests that's not possible though, so I'll settle for whatever it is). About $n$, I don't care particularly.