# Bounding integral expression with Sobolev norm of integrand

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Consider the following integral expression:
$$\mathcal I :=\iint_{\epsilon \leq|x-y| \leq 1/2} f(x) f(y) \frac{\langle g(x)-g(y), x-y\rangle}{|x-y|^{n+2}}  d x d y $$
for $\epsilon>0$, $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R)$ and *$f$ compactly supported* (NB compact support assumption added later).

If $g \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n;\mathbb R^n)$ (for any $p \in (1,\infty]$), is it true that $$\mathcal I \lesssim \|\nabla g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}$$
or something similar (possibly adding the $\epsilon$ somewhere)?

Related questions are [Bounding integral expression with total variation of integrand](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425400/bounding-integral-expression-with-total-variation-of-integrand?rq=1)  and [Bounding integral expression with BV norm of integrand](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425441/bounding-integral-expression-with-bv-norm-of-integrand)

Comment: Do you want a specific dependence on $n$ and/or $\epsilon$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Ideally no dependence on $\epsilon$ (or bounded coefficient as $\epsilon \to 0$); for $n$ I don't have a guess

Comment: As the previous answer (for $n=1$ and $p=1$) shows, the exact bound explodes to $\infty$ as $\epsilon\downarrow0$. So, bounded dependence on $\epsilon$ is not possible in this generality. Also, it would be good to know in advance what kind of dependence on $n$ would be satisfactory for you.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I was hoping that the dependence on $\epsilon$ would improve passing from $p=1$ to $p>1$. For the dependence on $n$, I don't care particularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a bound is impossible already for $n=1$. Indeed, suppose that $f=1$ and
$$g'(x)=\frac1{1+|x|}$$
for all real $x$. Then $TV(g)=\infty$ and hence, according to the [previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425408/36721), $\mathcal I=\infty$, whereas $\|\nabla g\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}<\infty$ for any $p\in(1,\infty]$.

Comment: How does this not work? Shouldn't the situation improve passing from $p=1$ to $p>1$ or at least not worsen since $L^p_{loc} \subset L^1_{loc}$?

Comment: @Dal : The reasoning here is very simple (modulo the previous answer), and it shows that no, $p>1$ is not better than $p=1$. As for the local inclusion, it is irrelevant; relevant is the global behavior.

Comment: My mistake: I forgot to add $f$ is compactly supported.

Comment: By the way, does the compact support assumption help in getting rid of the $\epsilon$ dependence in the estimate in 1d?

Comment: @Dal : You should not change your question so as to invalidate a valid answer (especially given that the compact support condition did not appear in your other, closely related, questions either). So, please restore the original question. If you choose to post the amended question separately, please specify the meaning of $\lesssim$, including the specific kinds of dependence of the corresponding constant on $f,g,n,\epsilon$ that you require. These conditions should be well thought out and re-checked before you post, and you should assume full responsibility for your posts.

Comment: I don't think it helps to add another question with only a slight modification. But I'll keep the original one and open up a bounty as soon as possible for further incentive related to the compact support assumption.

Comment: @Dal  You really should not add an assumption to a question after it has been answered. You should accept the answer, and then post another question. Otherwise people will not spend effort thinking about your questions.